# ifelse value specified amount less than other value then

Tags: if-statement, sum, equals

Apologies all, I'm new to R and am stumped on something that I am sure is simple!

I have this working code: `lr5yr$"LR_3Y_>10%_over_5Y" <- ifelse(lr5yr$lr >= 0.65 & lr5yr$lr - lr5yr$lr5 < lr5yr$lr ,"Y","N")`

Effectively all I need is at the end to specify how much less the final calculation is.

In my formula the end is show a Y if the value of lr-lr5 is less than lr. But what I need is for it to show a Y only if the amount less is greater than or equal to 0.1

So, if lr-lr5 is 0.1 or greater less than lr show Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that what I want could be achieved with a slight modification to my formula above, however I needed a quick fix so managed to come up with a workaround.

I created a new column using the following `lr5yr$"LR_Diff" <- lr5yr$lr - lr5yr$lr5` and then derived my require Y/N flag with the following code: `lr5yr$"LR_3Y_>10%_over_5Y" <- ifelse(lr5yr$lr >= 0.65 & lr5yr$LR_Diff > .1 ,"Y","N")`